# Using RegisterWaitForSingleObject if operation completes first

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm doing some asynchronous network I/O using Begin/End style methods. (It's actually a query against Azure Table Storage, but I don't think that matters.) I've implemented a client side timeout using the `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`. This is working fine as far as I can tell.

Because `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` takes a `WaitHandle` as an argument, I have to begin the I/O operation, then execute `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`. It seems like this introduces the possibility that the I/O completes before I even register the wait.

A simplified code sample:

```
private void RunQuery(QueryState queryState)
{
    //Start I/O operation
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = queryState.Query.BeginExecuteSegmented(NoopAsyncCallback, queryState);

    //What if the I/O operation completes here? 

    queryState.TimeoutWaitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, QuerySegmentCompleted, asyncResult, queryTimeout, true);
}

private void QuerySegmentCompleted(object opState, bool timedOut){
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = opState as IAsyncResult;
    QueryState state = asyncResult.AsyncState as QueryState;

    //If the I/O completed quickly, could TimeoutWaitHandle could be null here?
    //If so, what do I do about that?
    state.TimeoutWaitHandle.Unregister(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle);
}
```

What's the proper way to handle this? Do I still need to worry about `Unregister()`'ing the AsyncWaitHandle? If so, is there a fairly easy way to wait for it to be set?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a `Thread.Sleep` in the middle to allow time for the I/O operation to complete, and see what happens?

Comment: I have not. I think I've seen this happen only maybe 3-4 times, and then only on heavily loaded production machines. I'd rather not start adding Sleep() calls into my real code.

Comment: Test it in your development environment of course.  When you say you've seen this happen only 3-4 times, what have you seen happen?  A random unexplained NullPointerException?

Comment: Exactly, a NullPointerException on Unregister() line.

Comment: Why aren't you setting the callback in `BeginExecuteSegmented`, since it provides such an option?  Otherwise, I don't see how you can avoid that possible race condition.

Comment: If I set the callback in BeginExecuteSegmented, there is no client side timeout. That's why I'm using RegisterWaitForSingleObject(). If there's a better way to approach that problem, that would work too.

Comment: Gotcha. It seems like there needs to be a callback in `BeginExecuteSegmented` that cancels the wait operation, so that if that callback is hit first, the timeoutwait set at the end is ignored.

Comment: You mean instead of a NoopCallback, use a callback that sets a flag which can be examined before the wait operation? I think that would just be a slightly different race condition. But I could maybe do that and check the flag after the wait is executed - if the flag is set then immediately unregister the WaitHandle. You should put that in as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you and everyone else has this problem. And it does not matter if the IO completed synchronously or not. There is still a race between the callback and the assignment. Microsoft should have provided the `RegisteredWaitHandle` to that callback function automatically. That would have solved everything. Oh well, hindsight is always 20-20 as they say.

What you need to do is keep reading the `RegisteredWaitHandle` variable until it is no longer null. It is okay to do this in a tight loop because the race is subtle enough that the loop will not be spinning around very many times.

```
private void RunQuery(QueryState queryState)
{
  // Start the operation.
  var asyncResult = queryState.Query.BeginExecuteSegmented(NoopAsyncCallback, queryState);

  // Register a callback.
  RegisteredWaitHandle shared = null;
  RegisteredWaitHandle produced = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle,
    (state, timedout) =>
    {
      var asyncResult = opState as IAsyncResult;
      var state = asyncResult.AsyncState as QueryState;
      while (true)
      {
        // Keep reading until the value is no longer null.
        RegisteredWaitHandle consumed = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref shared, null, null);
        if (consumed != null)
        {
          consumed.Unregister(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle);
          break;
        }
      }
    }, asyncResult, queryTimeout, true);

  // Publish the RegisteredWaitHandle so that the callback can see it.
  Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref shared, produced, null);
}
```

Comment: I think I see what you're driving at here. Is it really necessary to have the two RegisteredWaitHandle variables, and the CompareExchange()? Since pointer assignment is an atomic operation, can't I just examine the `produced` variable inside the callback?

Comment: @breischl: Well, you need a memory barrier so that you get a "fresh read" of the variable on each iteration. You'd probably be okay to omit the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` call because I'm sure `RegisteredWaitHandle.Unregistered` generates a memory barrier as well. But, personally, I'd stick with this pattern because `Interlocked.CompareExchange` makes it explicit.

Comment: Wouldn't declaring `produced` as `volatile` have the same effect?

Comment: @breischl: Absolutely, except that you *cannot* declare a local variable as `volatile`. But, you have the right idea. And of course, you could restructure the code so that you could use `volatile`. There are lot of valid ways to do that.

Comment: Ah, right, dang. By the way, thanks for answering my many followup questions. Just two more (I think): Would a `Thread.VolatileRead()` suffice? Also would it be worthwhile to do a `Thread.Yield()` or a  inside of the `while(true)` loop?

Comment: Because you can't do `Thread.VolatileRead()` on a local variable either. Sorry, I should've checked that before asking.

Comment: @breischl: `Thread.VolatileRead` would work, but it does not have a generic overload so you'd have to declare the shared variable as `object` and then do a bunch of casting...icky. `Thread.Yield`, `Thread.Sleep(0)`, and `Thread.Sleep(1)` all could be useful in the tight loop. I describe what each one does in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10509457/158779). Personally, I wouldn't  bother with either because the time lag between the read and write is already going to be incredibly small.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to Unregister if the I/O completed before the timeout as it was the completion that signalled your callback.  In fact upon reading the docs of the Unregister method it seems totally unnecessary to call it as you are executing only once and you are not Unregistering in an unrelated method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.registeredwaithandle.unregister.aspx

> If a callback method is in progress when Unregister executes, waitObject is not signaled until the callback method completes. In particular, if a callback method executes Unregister, waitObject is not signaled until that callback method completes.

Comment: I think the quoted documentation is saying it won't signal my operation's WaitHandle. It doesn't seem to say anything about the RegisteredWaitHandle I got from the ThreadPool. But it is terribly confusing, so I could be wrong. The documentation on RegisterWaitForSingleObject() explicitly says you should always Unregister(), so I think I do need to do it somewhere. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9f75h7a.aspx

Comment: @breischl is QuerySegmentCompleted only called as a call back from RegisterWaitForSingleObject?

Comment: This is a good question btw.  If state.TimeoutWaitHandle is null you could potentially leave the unregistering of the WaitHandle up to the Finalizer thread which is not optimal.  At the same time the documentation states that you should always Unregister which is impossible in your case.